# The unexpected behaviour of swapping in python list

Tags: python-3.x, swap

Here I want to swap the 4 and 2 in the given list by the help of indices and hence I write the below code.

```
>>>arr = [4,3,1,2]
>>> arr[0] , arr[arr[0]-1] = arr[arr[0]-1] ,arr[0]
>>> arr
[2, 4, 1, 2]
```

The above code gives an unexpected output as you can see. The expected output was [2,3,1,4].

But When I write as

```
>>>arr = [4,3,1,2]
>>>index = arr[0] - 1
>>>arr[0] , arr[index] = arr[index] ,arr[0]
>>>arr
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

The output comes as expected.

Why is that?

Edit:
Yes there are other way to swap a first and last element. I had necessity to choose this approach after which i came across this abnormal behavior. For which i have not yet found any explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[0], arr[-1] = arr[-1], arr[0]
```

?

Apparently, both tuples are evaluated left-to-right in parallel, and evaluation of the second element of LHS tuple is sequenced after the change to the first element, so assigning the first element to the LHS tuple causes even a different reference to be its second element.

Comment: I know that would work but when I write in this way arr[arr[0]-1]  the answer is not as expected hence got me curious why is that happening. Searched for a while but no explanation.

Comment: Apparently, both tuples are evaluated left-to-right in parallel, and evaluation of the second element of LHS tuple is sequenced after the change to the first element, so assigning the first element to the LHS tuple causes even a different reference to be the second element.

Comment: When you use `arr[0] , arr[arr[0]-1] = arr[arr[0]-1] ,arr[0]`, the `arr[arr[0]-1]` on the left hand side is evaluated _after_ `arr[0]` has changed, so you get `2-1` instead of `4-1`.

Comment: Yeah this explanation makes so much sense. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Backward indices in Python should be given as `-num`:

```
>>> arr = [4,3,1,2]
>>> arr[0] , arr[-1] = arr[-1] ,arr[0]
>>> arr
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

Comment: I know that would work but when I write in this way the answer is not as expected hence got me curious why is that happening. Searched for a while but no explanation.